# NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Sign in"}

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**I exported Selenium IDE to Python WebDriver and when I run it. I get this error: Something wrong with exception or Sign in id. 
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Sign in"}**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import unittest, time, re

class Vova(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = `"https://www.yahoo.com/`"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True

    def test_vova(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get("https://uk.yahoo.com")
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Mail").click()
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("Sign in").click()
        driver.find_element_by_id("login-username").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("login-username").send_keys("")
        driver.find_element_by_id("passwd-field").clear()
        driver.find_element_by_id("passwd-field").send_keys("")

    def is_element_present(self, how, what):
        try: self.driver.find_element(by=how, value=what)
        except NoSuchElementException as e: return False
        return True

    def is_alert_present(self):
        try: self.driver.switch_to_alert()
        except NoAlertPresentException as e: return False
        return True

    def close_alert_and_get_its_text(self):
        try:
            alert = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
            alert_text = alert.text
            if self.accept_next_alert:
                alert.accept()
            else:
                alert.dismiss()
            return alert_text
        finally: self.accept_next_alert = True

    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 3):

[`find_element_by_link_text()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_link_text) would only find links - `a` elements, but on the [UK Yahoo Mail](https://uk.mail.yahoo.com/?.intl=uk&.lang=en-GB) page the `Sign in` text is inside a `div`:

```
<div id="signin" class="helvetica-bold uppercase">Sign in</div>
```

Use the "By XPath" locator instead:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[. = 'Sign in']").click()
```

Or, the "By ID":

```
driver.find_element_by_id("signin").click()
```

Comment: @vladbelo replace `passwd-field` with `login-passwd`. Please accept the answer so that we can resolve the topic. Thanks.